# XSLT alternate parsing output depending on a certain value of an attribute

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML message that I need in name/value pairs and need certain values filled only if there if "Payment" value is present in the name attribute of the extendedDataElements tag. If the value is "Payment" then:

- A new name/pair is created with Status as the name and the value being the data that is in the situationQualifier
- The situationQualifier is then filled with some static value that I will hardcode
- The amount tag in the name/value is then changed to trnAmount with its corresponding value.

If the value of the name attribute is anything other than "Payment", then it just reverts to the basic transformation of "element_attribute=value,". I have done the basic transformation to get into name value pairs, but am having much trouble with the conditional step to apply these modifications based on this extendedDataElements value.

Thank you for any help.

**XML**

```
    <cbe:CommonBaseEvent>
    <sourceComponentId component="28591" />
    <situationInformation extensionName="Payment">
      <extendedDataElements name="Payment">
        <children name="amount">
          <values>100</values>
        </children>
      </extendedDataElements>
      <situationType situationQualifier="PaymentCompletionReceived" reasoningScope="INFO"/>
    </situationInformation>
</cbe:CommonBaseEvent>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
sourceComponentId_component=28591, extendedDataElements_name=Channel, trnAmount=100, Status=PaymentCompletionReceived, situationType_situationQualifier=StaticValueHere, situationType_reasoningScope=INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define a template like the one below to define custom processing of the data ? I think it should handle that case perfectly. This the declarative way of handling the problem.

```
<xsl:template match="extendedDataElements[@name='Payment']">

</xsl:template>
```